# Python fails to present a module's docstring in ```help(<module>)``` saying it doesn't recognize the module

Tags: python, docstring

---

Python presents the docstrings for functions in `help(...)` but fails to present the docstring for the module the functions are defined in.

Answer (score 1):

I imported the module with `import <module name> as <other name>` and used `help(<module name>)`. All good, problem solved.